# Filter jobs/candidates by "working remotely"

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, jobs

I believe it would be a good improvement, to add the option to filter jobs by "working remotely" in the locations filter.

This would make it much easier to find those jobs/candidates interested in working remotely. At the moment, you need to go through a list of job postings and read the whole post to see if they write something about working remotely.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Done...

[image]

and done.[image]

:)

Comment: Too bad. I am officially blind!